# Limit of ratio of integral of a function and function

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to find conditions on f(t) for when a nonzero limit of $h(t)$ (below) exists and the value of $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} h(t)$.

\begin{equation*}
 h(t)=\frac{1}{f(t)}\int^t_0f(s)ds
\end{equation*}
where the following are assumed to hold
\begin{align}
(i)&~~f(t)\rightarrow \infty\\
(ii)&~~ \frac{f(t)}{f'(t)}\rightarrow \infty\\
(iii)&~~ f(x) ~~~\text{is  continuous and differentiable}
\end{align}

(ii) implies that L'Hopital's Rule doesn't apply. Note that no polynomial works.  $f(t) =e^{at}$ works.  So, it seems f(t) and its antiderivative must be asymptotically close in some sense.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that $h(t)$ can be "solved" and written as

$$h(t) = \frac{F(t) - F(0)}{f(t)}$$

Where $F$ denotes the primitive of $f$.

In the general expression above you require for example the limits to exist (even if they are infinite, with opportune other conditions) and $F(0)$ to exist (cannot be infinite).

Clearly, up to all this, you must have $f(s)$ continuous everywhere in the interval of integration.

It's obvious that no polynomial works, since their primitive increases the degree by one, and the limit would be infinite.

Combination of polynomials and exponentials do work. For example:

$$f(t) = P(t)e^{-at}$$

Where $P(t)$ is a polynomial of degree $n > 0$.

$$\lim_{t\to +\infty} \frac{1}{P(t)e^{-at}}\int_0^t P(s)e^{-as}\ \text{d}s$$

If we take even just the fist term gotten by an integration by parts we have

$$-\frac{P(s)}{a}e^{-as}\bigg|_0^t \rightarrow -\frac{P(t)e^{-at}}{a} + \frac{P(0)}{a}$$

Now $P(0)$ may or may not be zero, we care not much about. It's a number.

Just by this term we have

$$\lim_{t\to +\infty} \frac{-\frac{P(t)e^{-at}}{a} + \frac{P(0)}{a}}{P(t) e^{-at}} = -\frac{1}{a}$$

Which is not zero.

The following terms obtained from the integration by parts (which you should repeat until you have lowed down the degree of $P(s)$ to zero, that is getting a number) will give you limit zero.

There ar emany functions that will suit your request.

I suspect that you will like the Schwarz space, the space of rapidly decreasing functions. I think it could suit good for your purposes.